# Range of exponential functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have to find the range of $4^{\sin(x)}+ 2^{\sin(x)+3}=2^{2\sin(x)}+ 8\cdot2^{\sin(x)}$. 
Let's take $y=2^{\sin x}$, so we rewrite the equation as $y^2+8y=0$.
The range of this function is $[-16,+\infty) $, however, I get $2^{\sin x}=-16$ and that's there I'm stuck.
I have a similar problem with $9^x+12\cdot3^x+27$. I rewrite it as $x^2+12x+27$. The range is $[-9, \infty)$ and I don't know how to apply this to the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of computing the range by using quadratic functions is correct, but you should take care of the domain once you change the variable from $x$ to $y$ because $y=2^{\sin(x)}$ can only assume values on $[2^{-1},2]$. Try to decide the range of $y^2+8y$ with domain restricted to $[2^{-1},2]$.

Comment: So I just calculate $y^2+8y$ on 1/2 and 2?

Comment: Make sure you understand what will happen when you change variables from $x$ to $y=f(x)$: the domain of the new variable $y$ need to be the range of the function $f(x)$. That's exactly where you get stuck, because $2^{\sin(x)}$ can never assume value -16.

Comment: If I understand correctly, since the range of $2^(sin^(x))$ is $[1/2,2]$, and y is monotonic and increasing in $[1/2, 2]$, f(1/2) and f(2) will be the minimum and maximum.

Comment: Exactly, by the way it should be “the range of $2^{\sin(x)}$ is [1/2,2]”, the domain of $2^{\sin(x)}$ is still the domain of $\sin(x)$ which is $\mathbb{R}$, but I think you understand it.

Comment: I can apply this to the second problem, right? the range of $3^x$ is $(0, ∞)$, and f is increasing in that interval, so f(0)=27 will be the minimum.
Thanks alot!